# Drawing Spheres with RadialGradientBrush

Tags: c#, wpf, drawing, gradient, radial-gradients

I'm trying to draw spherical pieces for a game, in WPF.
Pieces are drawns as Elipses with RadialGradientBrushs.
As you can see below, my black pieces look fantastic,
but it is hard to get the white ones having any depth without making them look grey.

[image]

I'm currently using:

```
private readonly Brush _whitePieceBrush = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.Snow, Colors.Ivory);
private readonly Brush _blackPieceBrush = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Black);

...

using (DrawingContext dc = _piecesVisual.RenderOpen())
{
    ....
    Brush brush = piece.Value.IsBlack ? _blackPieceBrush : _whitePieceBrush;
    var pen = new Pen(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black), 0.5); 
    dc.DrawEllipse(brush, pen, new Point(posX, posY), 15, 15);
    ...

}
```

The black circles around the white pieces don't help, but with out them, it looks even worse. (If I can find a good way to draw them that looks better, I'll be removing it)

Comment: screw that it looks fun i wanna play it :D

Comment: when it is done and submitted (it is for a uni project), i'll probably put up a link to the source and the installer (will link into the main post)

Comment: paraphrasing Field of Dreams here but "Compile it, and they shall come"

Comment: Looking around my office, I note that most white things that have depth (i.e. all real things) look gray as part of their depth. The parts that stay consistently white don't really appear to have depth (from the color - obviously I can discern it from perspective and whatnot).

Comment: yes, definately some grey is needed, but so far my expeiments with Colors.Silver, made it too grey.
I think it is all about how you define the colour points

Comment: this is probably why people sometimes revert to using blue and red as piece colours to avoid the greyscale on white objects

Comment: Basically, you need some gray. Experiment until you find something that looks good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried:

```
    private readonly Brush _whitePieceBrush = new RadialGradientBrush()
    {
        GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
        {

            new GradientStop(Colors.WhiteSmoke,0.3),
            new GradientStop(Colors.LightGray, 1.0),


        }
    };
    private readonly Brush _whitePieceBorder = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
```

[image: Board Picture]

---

Taking Clemens' advice and having them off center:
**With them a bit off center:**
I think this helps the black more than the white, but still and improvement

```
    private static readonly Point _lightSource = new Point(0.3, 0.35);

    private readonly Brush _blackPieceBrush = new RadialGradientBrush(Colors.DarkGray, Colors.Black)
    {
        GradientOrigin = _lightSource
    };
    private readonly Brush _blackPieceBorder = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);

    private readonly Brush _whitePieceBrush = new RadialGradientBrush()
    {
        GradientOrigin = _lightSource,
        GradientStops = new GradientStopCollection
        {

            new GradientStop(Colors.WhiteSmoke,0.3),
            new GradientStop(Colors.LightGray, 1.0),

        }
    };
    private readonly Brush _whitePieceBorder = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Silver);
```

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect. Did you also try to make it a bit off-center?

Comment: Yes i did (actually immediately after uploading the first image)

Answer (score 12):

What about something like the following. The focal point is a bit off-center, which i find improves the spatial impression.

[image]

```
<Ellipse Width="60" Height="60">
    <Ellipse.Fill>
        <RadialGradientBrush GradientOrigin="0.3,0.3">
            <RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.3"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="1"/>
            </RadialGradientBrush.GradientStops>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </Ellipse.Fill>
</Ellipse>
```

Comment: Doesn't come out so great for me for some reason.
Really obvious banding, on my computer